# Adjusting CSS for table related HTML tags

Tags: css

I have an ancient HTML tabled based web form I am trying to style and have very limited control over the HTML, so I must use the table structure that is in place.

I see there is a border around the table, which apparently is being styled with the following:

```
tbody tr td {
border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
}
```

It is inside a div class called **lead-form**, which appears to be unique through the site. How would I target just this specific table inside the div so that nothing else on the site gets knocked out that uses tables?

Comment: Are there more than one table inside `.lead-form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it if `.lead-form` really is unique.

```
.lead-form tbody tr td 
{
    /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually the only element in that div you could use this selector

```
div#lead-form tbody tr td {

}
```

Note: Sorry, if it's a class it's rather

```
div.lead-form tbody tr td {

}
```